# Honeycomb - Status Bar Hidden during AlertDialog

Tags: android, visibility, android-alertdialog, statusbar

I have a problem with the status bar visibility in Honeycomb (3.2) while showing an AlertDialog. In my HomeActivity I set the status bar visibility to hidden by the following code:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.toplevelview);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

So far this works great and should stay so in my whole application. But when I create a new AlertDialog via the AlertDialogBuilder and show it the status bar visibility isn't hidden any more. Do I have to set the status bar visibility explicitly again or something? I have tried a few things, but nothing themes to work.

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I think each activity and dialog needs to set it.

This works, sort of:

```
protected void onPrepareDialog (int id, Dialog dialog) {
    View main_layout = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    main_layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
}
```

The problem is, at least in the Honeycomb ROM I'm developing with (Flashback 10.3), you still get a brief flash of the status bar as the dialog is shown, or so it seems.  I'm a noob, so I might be doing dialogs wrong.

Actually, I KNOW I'm doing dialogs wrong because "onPrepareDialog" is deprecated ([linky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog%29)).  I'll be figuring out fragments and the fragment manager next.

The only other time I still can't hide the status bar is when the choices pop-up for a spinner.  Seems like this should be an app level setting...